# Firebase Erorr on Flutter: Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':firebase_core:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, firebase-authentication

hei im new on firebase flutter, and i want to make login page with auth with firebase. and after i make login page and all setup fromo documentation for firebase to my project i get this erorr.
I try  `pub clear cache` and its not solving the problem.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':firebase_core:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':firebase_core:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-common:.
     Required by:
         project :firebase_core 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this is my pubspec.yaml with the latest version firebase

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.18.0
  animate_icons: ^1.0.0
  motion_tab_bar: ^0.1.5
  simple_animations: ^1.3.3
  #firebase
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0+1
  provider: ^4.3.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "id.skyward.plantgo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')

  // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
  // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

  // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}

rootProject.ext {
  set('FlutterFire', [
    FirebaseSDKVersion: '25.12.0'
  ])
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5' // Google Services plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UPDATE`

I found the answer for this. at the `app/build.gradle`files, this line `FirebaseSDKVersion: '25.12.0'` is the problem.
Its should be same version with `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')`
so i change to `FirebaseSDKVersion: '25.12.0'` then firebase core its work.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your `app/build.gradle` file please try this.

I have just add one line `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'`.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "id.skyward.plantgo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')

  // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
  // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

  // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'

}

rootProject.ext {
  set('FlutterFire', [
    FirebaseSDKVersion: '25.12.0'
  ])
}
```

Comment: hei thx for answer, i have try from your solving. but still same erorr

Comment: @skyward17 Please try now new code because I have just some add one line

Comment: i try to add that line too, sadly still same erorr for me